# @input listener not working for a custom component

Tags: vue.js, events, vuejs2, primevue

I am currently trying to use a custom component from the **PrimeVue library**, it literally states that you are able to use any event: *"Any valid event such as focus, blur and input are passed to the underlying input element."*

For me the event listener works, but I need to use ENTER or click outside the input in order to make it work. This doesn't occur when using a regular HTML-tag.

This is the line of code which I am trying to make work without needing to press ENTER:

```
<InputNumber v-model="product.quantity" min="1" :max="product.units" @input="checkUnits(product)" />
```

And this is the line of code with the same event which doesn't require an ENTER press:

```
<input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" :max="product.units" v-model="product.quantity" class="col-md-2 float-left" @input="checkUnits(product)">
```

I have also tried to change the event to **v-on:keyup**, but that automatically clears any new input given.

This is the link to the component for reference: https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase-v2/#/inputnumber

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `v-model.enter="product.quantity"`?

Comment: Seems to work, but only after I click with my mouse outside the input. *EDIT: also does this without the .enter

Comment: I think I found something: "For v-model to work on custom components, you need to manually $emit an 'input' event: https://jsfiddle.net/gypskp9h/" but not sure, because it does emit the event, just not in the right way no?

Comment: *UPDATE: seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/506

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue, here is the ticket:
https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/issues/506

When I change the InputNumber to an InputText component, it does work, I can also use the "type" property here. I see this as a solution, therefore it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to simply use the event and use the value:

Here is a example of the event object ($event) returned from @input.
[event object example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSt9e.png)

From what I see,
The $event.value is the current updated value.
The $event.formattedValue is the value before the input, in string form.

Therefore, my solution was :

<InputNumber v-model=quantity autofocus @input="onQuantityChange($event.value)"/>